# How to convert normal map into bump map

Tags: node-editor, normal-map

I wonder how to do that in Blender. I desire to extract images of bump maps from normal maps, so that I can re-work them in Krita or any other painting software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no built in method that converts a Normal map to a Bump in Blender. It would be possible to write a python script to do this but it would take much research to be able to produce desirable results.

I only know of one tool that can do this and that is Substance Designer.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have just bought ShaderMap ($49) yesterday, as I want nothing to do with Adobe, which has bought Substance Painter and Substance Designer. ShaderMap is for editing maps; its tools include brushes probably for all map types. I'm currently exploring ShaderMap and taking tutorials on it. I think ShaderMap & BPainter addon might make a good combination as an alternative to Substance Painter. 
 https://shadermap.com/home/